# garbage collector calls in during rendering a simple screen (libgdx)

Tags: java, garbage-collection, libgdx

I was testing my almost finished game (created with libgdx) for garbage collection.
I ran my desktop version with verbose gc and only 2mb heap VM options.

I was sort of worried to notice that gc kicks in every once in a while during screen rendering.

I decided to create a simple screen with a single stage and add one Image actor to it.
No other objects created. I noticed that even with such a simple set up gc kicks in every once in a while.

With the code below I get two gc calls after running for about 5 minutes:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;

public class TestScreen implements Screen {

   private static final float viewportWidth = 40f;
   private static final float viewportHeight = 24f;

   private final Assets assets = new Assets();
   private Stage stage;

   @Override
   public void render(float delta) {
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      stage.act();
      stage.draw();
   }

   @Override
   public void resize(int width, int height) {
   }

   @Override
   public void show() {
      stage = new Stage(viewportWidth, viewportHeight, false);
      Image image = new Image(assets.getMenuSkin(), "stars");
      image.setSize(viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
      image.setPosition(0f, 0f);
      stage.addActor(image);
   }

   @Override
   public void hide() {
   }

   @Override
   public void pause() {
   }

   @Override
   public void resume() {
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose() {
      assets.dispose();
      stage.dispose();
   }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
[GC [DefNew: 998K->4K(1024K), 0.0014329 secs] 2336K->1359K(3124K), 0.0015340 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
[GC [DefNew: 964K->3K(1024K), 0.0005355 secs] 2319K->1358K(3124K), 0.0006174 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
```

And the summary:

```
Heap
def new generation total 1024K, used 133K [0x323c0000, 0x324d0000, 0x325c0000)
eden space 960K, 13% used [0x323c0000, 0x323e0918, 0x324b0000)
from space 64K, 5% used [0x324c0000, 0x324c0d10, 0x324d0000)
to space 64K, 0% used [0x324b0000, 0x324b0000, 0x324c0000)
tenured generation total 2100K, used 1355K [0x325c0000, 0x327cd000, 0x329c0000)
the space 2100K, 64% used [0x325c0000, 0x32712c48, 0x32712e00, 0x327cd000)
compacting perm gen total 12288K, used 2520K [0x329c0000, 0x335c0000, 0x369c0000)
the space 12288K, 20% used [0x329c0000, 0x32c36140, 0x32c36200, 0x335c0000)
ro space 10240K, 54% used [0x369c0000, 0x36f3daf0, 0x36f3dc00, 0x373c0000)
rw space 12288K, 55% used [0x373c0000, 0x37a61ce8, 0x37a61e00, 0x37fc0000)
```

*Is it OpenGL data being send over arrays that gets garbage collected?*

From what I read in Mario's book (Beginning Android Games) I figure it is not the case.
As far as I remember, Mario wrote about a bug that made gc run in this case but it existed only in early Android versions.

*Or maybe the desktop implementation runs gc and Android doesn't?*

Comment: Knowing little about the openGL library you are using I wonder how often show() is called? It creates a new image every time and might litter the heap with too many objects forcing GC to kick in a lot.

Comment: show() is called only once when the screen is supposed to be shown. I tend to put all creation logic here because I used to get some context not initialized error when I was creating libgdx stuff in a class constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DDMS heap tracker tool.  It will tell you exactly what is being allocated and the backtrace to it being allocated.  See "Tracking memory allocation of objects" in:
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

Of course, this will be specific to Android, but since 99% of the Libgdx code is the same (e.g., all of scene2d is the same), it should highlight if the allocations are coming from Libgdx, or Lwjgl, or even the JVM (Hotspot might be re-compiling methods in the background, I'm not sure where allocations for that show up).

Which version of Libgdx are you using?

There are some code paths in the scene2d that will allocate new objects, but they're generally then stored in a `Pool`, so they shouldn't get collected (and the allocations should eventually slow down and stop).

Comment: I'm using 0.9.7, jar dated 2012-11-27. Since libgdx is constantly evolving I'll try to update and see if it helps. I know scene2d pools some objects like Actions for instance (which are very cool by the way). My game actually makes gc kick in 3-5 times a minute with minumum 2mb heap size even though I was extra careful not to use 'new', pure Strings, java collection iterators in for loops, autoboxing etc in my code. Thanks for the info on the tracking tool. Next, I was actually going to ask which one I should use to get full info on what is going on. Maybe it will help me pin down the problem.

Comment: Let us know what you find!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to analyze running the above code in libgdx desktop first.
With 2MB heap, two first GC calls occured 58 seconds and 241 seconds after the application had been started:

```
58.163: [GC 58.163: [DefNew: 1024K->19K(1088K), 0.0013214 secs] 2367K->1440K(3328K), 0.0014552 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
241.027: [GC 241.027: [DefNew: 1043K->17K(1088K), 0.0008428 secs] 2464K->1439K(3328K), 0.0009747 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
```

I grabbed the heap a couple of seconds before **the second** GC call with MAT, and a couple of seconds after.
While analyzing the outputs, I spotted differences only in unreachable objects.

Here they are in desending order based on the difference between the object count before and after the second GC call:

```
Before GC call:                                                    |After GC call:
Class Name                                | Objects | Shallow Heap |Objects | Shallow Heap |

java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU               |    19753|        948144|     864|         41472|
int[]                                     |     2599|        218168|    2507|        207152|
java.lang.Class[]                         |      140|          2384|     133|          2248|
java.lang.reflect.Constructor             |       42|          2688|      35|          2240|
char[]                                    |    11588|        602008|   11584|        601808|
java.lang.String                          |    11237|        269688|   11233|        269592|
java.io.FileDescriptor                    |        4|            96|       1|            24|
java.io.FileInputStream                   |        4|            96|       1|            24|
java.lang.Object                          |        6|            48|       3|            24|
java.lang.ref.Finalizer                   |        4|           128|       1|            32|
java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger |        4|            64|       1|            16|
java.lang.reflect.Constructor[]           |        5|           160|       3|            96|
```

The main huge difference is DirrectFloutBufferU.
So, it appears I was right about OpenGL data buffers being garbage collected.
It seems to be the case because when I added more actors to be rendered I got more frequent GC calls.

The rest of the differences is insignificant. I don't know how to explain them, though.

*Is this correct behaviour?*

As soon as I find some time I will run a similar test in Android.

Comment: It seems bad to me.  Its as likely to be part of LWJGL and not part of Libgdx (or perhaps some part of Libgdx is using the wrong LWJGL API).  As a StackOverflow aside, this "answer" should probaby be an extension/edit of your original question and not posted as an "answer".

Comment: Sorry about posting an 'answer'. Next time I'll do as you wrote :)

Comment: Mario Zechner himself gave his answer to this issue here: http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=8786#p40099. He claims it is normal for a desktop application.